# Remove duplicate documents from Topdocs

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene 4.10.4

If I merge two TopDocs containing some same documents, the resulting TopDocs contains duplicate documents.

```
TopDocs[] array={topDocs1,topDocs2};
TopDocs finalDocs= TopDocs.merge(null,1000,array);
```

Is there any way to remove duplicate documents while merging?

Comment: how do you want to remove duplicates? which out of 2 duplicates should stay? with maximum score? or minimum?

Comment: Scoring doesn't matter. Because I'll sort the documents based on index time. So, any of the documents can be removed. Either maximum or minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we make an assumption, that duplicated documents are the documents, that have same `docId`, than following code should help you:

```
        final TopDocs merge = TopDocs.merge(1000, new TopDocs[]{topDocs1, topDocs2});
        Set<ScoreDoc> scoreDocs = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<ScoreDoc>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ScoreDoc o1, ScoreDoc o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o1.doc, o2.doc);
            }
        });
        float maxScore = Float.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < merge.scoreDocs.length; ++i) {
            final ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs1 = merge.scoreDocs;
            scoreDocs.add(scoreDocs1[i]);
            if (scoreDocs1[i].score > maxScore) {
                maxScore = scoreDocs1[i].score;
            }
        }
        final TopDocs filteredTopDocs = new TopDocs(scoreDocs.size(), scoreDocs.toArray(new ScoreDoc[0]), maxScore);
```